# How to fade out loudness of an audio track?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio, graph-editor, movie-clip-editor

how can the loudness of an audio track in the VSE be faded out at the end of a track?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

highlight the strip, open panel (press <kbd>N</kbd>  if closed), find the *Volume* field and change the value.

You can animate the value, set to zero at the last frame and keyframe it by pressin <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering it, than $1$ (or any other) several frames earlier.